# usage of libstrophe library for xmpp

Tags: c, xmpp, libstrophe

I am trying to create a chat client in C using Libstrophe. I have referred to the following code example given at https://github.com/metajack/libstrophe/blob/master/examples/active.c
The code has a call to xmpp_connect_client(...) to establish a connection with the xmpp server.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
xmpp_ctx_t *ctx;
xmpp_conn_t *conn;

if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: active <jid> <pass>\n\n");
    return 1;
}

/* initialize lib */
xmpp_initialize();

/* create a context */
ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, NULL);

/* create a connection */
conn = xmpp_conn_new(ctx);

/* setup authentication information */
xmpp_conn_set_jid(conn, argv[1]);
xmpp_conn_set_pass(conn, argv[2]);

/* initiate connection */
xmpp_connect_client(conn, "talk.google.com", 0, conn_handler, ctx);

/* start the event loop */
xmpp_run(ctx);

/* release our connection and context */
xmpp_conn_release(conn);
xmpp_ctx_free(ctx);

/* shutdown lib */
xmpp_shutdown();

return 0;
```

}
But where does the authentication take place? I looked up the source code for libstrophe and found C file auth.c 
https://github.com/metajack/libstrophe/blob/master/src/auth.c
that has a function called _auth(..).
I tried using _auth(..) in my code but it does not perform authentication properly. i.e. it does not notify me of wrong user-name or password. 
Can any one suggest me the right way to authenticate my entity.

Comment: Oh, also note that you're linking to libstrophe's older repo (though there aren't currently many differences). It is now at https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libstrophe authenticates automatically when necessary. This happens inside xmpp_run(). The credentials it uses are set using these lines:

```
/* setup authentication information */
xmpp_conn_set_jid(conn, argv[1]);
xmpp_conn_set_pass(conn, argv[2]);
```

The `jid` is your address (such as "user@jabber.org", "user@gmail.com", "user@dukgo.com", etc.), and `pass` is your password.

Your example is missing your `conn_handler` function, which is where authentication errors will be delivered to.

Your `conn_handler` function should have a signature like this:

```
void conn_handler(xmpp_conn_t * const conn, const xmpp_conn_event_t status, 
                  const int error, xmpp_stream_error_t * const stream_error,
                  void * const userdata)
```

The parameters are:

`conn` - Your connection object.

`status` - One of `XMPP_CONN_CONNECT`, `XMPP_CONN_DISCONNECT` or `XMPP_CONN_FAIL`. When your connection handler function is called, this parameter tells you why it was called.

`error` - when disconnected (XMPP_CONN_FAIL), this contains the socket-level error code from the OS (otherwise it is 0).

`stream_error` - one of the possible stream errors, listed at [strophe.h:171](https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe/blob/master/strophe.h#L171), and their meaning documented in [RFC6120 section 4.9.3](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions).

`userdata` - This contains whatever you passed as the `userdata` parameter to `xmpp_connect_client()`. It is useful if you have some per-connection state to keep, and you don't want to use global variables or have multiple connections.

Finally, you shouldn't have to specify `"talk.google.com"` in `xmpp_connect_client()`, I recommend passing NULL instead.

Comment: I added the connection handler that checks the status and made the necessary changes. The connection to the server is made. But i get the same output even when i specify the wrong password. The command prompt displays:

Comment: xmpp DEBUG sock_connect to alt3.xmpp.l.google.com:5222 returned 304
xmpp DEBUG attempting to connect to alt3.xmpp.l.google.com
xmpp DEBUG connection successful
conn DEBUG SENT: <?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream to="gmail.com" xml:lang="en
" version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/str
eams">

Comment: xmpp DEBUG RECV: <stream:stream from='gmail.com' id='4EDF7B71A4D88935' version='
1.0' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client'>
xmpp DEBUG RECV: <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-t
ls"><required/></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><
mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism><mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism></mechanisms>
</stream:features>
TLSS DEBUG QuerySecurityPackageInfo() success
TLSS DEBUG AcquireCredentialsHandle() success

Comment: conn DEBUG SENT: <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>, error: 0
xmpp DEBUG RECV: <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
xmpp DEBUG handle proceedtls called for proceed
xmpp DEBUG proceeding with TLS
TLSS DEBUG QuerySecurityPackageInfo() success
TLSS DEBUG AcquireCredentialsHandle() success
xmpp DEBUG Couldn't start TLS! error -2146893032
conn DEBUG SENT: </stream:stream>
xmpp DEBUG parse error, disconnecting
xmpp DEBUG Closing socket.
DEBUG: disconnected
event DEBUG Stopping event loop.
event DEBUG Event loop completed.

Comment: how do i detect if the authentication has been made successfully? And handle the "couldn't start TLS " error,

Comment: The "couldn't start TLS" message is probably your issue. Make sure you compiled libstrophe with a TLS library (GnuTLS, OpenSSL, etc.). You will know authentication has succeeded when conn_handler is called with status == XMPP_CONN_CONNECT. P.S. I don't think comments are the appropriate place for debug logs here - please add them to your question (edit it) or create a new question if you feel this is a different issue.